# How can I print/encode a value into Dhall?

Tags: haskell, dhall

```
{-# LANGUAGE DeriveGeneric     #-}
{-# LANGUAGE OverloadedStrings #-}

import Dhall

data Example = Example { foo :: Natural, bar :: Vector Double }
    deriving (Generic, Show)

instance Interpret Example

main :: IO ()
main = do
  putStrLn "Hello, Haskell!"
  x <- input auto "./example.dhall"
  print (x :: Example)
```

In the above example, how can I instead encode an `Example` into a dhall value, so essentially a function of type `Example -> String`? Can't seem to find any reference to printing / encoding in haddocks.

Comment: You can use something like `Prettyprinter.Render.String.renderString . Dhall.Pretty.layout . Dhall.Pretty.prettyExpr` with the functions from http://hackage.haskell.org/package/dhall-1.34.0/docs/Dhall-Pretty.html and http://hackage.haskell.org/package/prettyprinter-1.7.0/docs/Prettyprinter-Render-String.html.

Comment: …but that's only the prettyprinting part. Use `ToDhall` to produce the `Expr`: http://hackage.haskell.org/package/dhall-1.34.0/docs/Dhall.html#t:ToDhall

Comment: Hmmm seems there were some changes between that version and 1.24 though, Dhall.Pretty.layout doesn't exist it seems. Will try figure this out though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is how you can pretty-print a Haskell value as the equivalent Dhall expression:

```
{-# LANGUAGE DeriveGeneric     #-}
{-# LANGUAGE DeriveAnyClass    #-}
{-# LANGUAGE OverloadedStrings #-}

import Dhall (FromDhall, Natural, ToDhall, Vector)
import Dhall.Pretty (CharacterSet(..))
import GHC.Generics (Generic)

import qualified Data.Text.Prettyprint.Doc.Render.Text as Prettyprint.Text
import qualified Dhall
import qualified Dhall.Pretty
import qualified Dhall.Core

data Example = Example { foo :: Natural, bar :: Vector Double }
    deriving (FromDhall, Generic, Show, ToDhall)

main :: IO ()
main = do
  x <- Dhall.input Dhall.auto "./example.dhall"

  let expression = Dhall.embed Dhall.inject (x :: Example)

  let doc = Dhall.Pretty.prettyCharacterSet Unicode expression

  Prettyprint.Text.putDoc doc
```

Comment: Note that the `Show` instance for `Doc` used by `print` uses a different layout algorithm than the one used in `dhall`. `dhall` uses `layoutSmart` which tries a bit harder to keep the document within 80 columns than `layoutPretty`, which the `Show` instance uses.

Comment: @sjakobi: I updated the code to use the better layout algorithm